# Old metal ceiling light box, wire clamp question

Tags: electrical

[image]

Do these clamps just tighten against the wire and not use any protection from the hole in the box? I was changing out a light fixture and thought I'd ask, since I was in it. I mean I guess it's been fine for 60+ years, but didn't know if it was still ok to use of if I need to install a plastic push in type connector or what....Thanks!

Comment: those are just fine to hold the cable in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those brackets don't need any bushings to hold the cable in place. Fit the cable against the bottom of the box and push the clamp straight down on the cable and tighten the screw. The sheathing on the cable should extend 1/4 to 1/2" beyond the clamp into the box.